# flutter web theme wrong going through docker

Tags: flutter, docker, dockerfile

I am using docker to host my flutter web app but the theme is showing wrong colors. The local build is showing the right colors.

My main.dart file:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  ConfigManager().init();
  Stripe.publishableKey = Config.publishableKey;
  Stripe.merchantIdentifier = 'merchant.flutter.stripe.test';
  await Stripe.instance.applySettings();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      initialRoute: Payment.routeName,
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        Payment.routeName: (_) => const Payment(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
#Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app
FROM debian:latest AS build-env

# Install flutter dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl git wget unzip libgconf-2-4 gdb libstdc++6 libglu1-mesa fonts-droid-fallback lib32stdc++6 python3
RUN apt-get clean

# Clone the flutter repo
RUN git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git /usr/local/flutter

# Set flutter path
ENV PATH="/usr/local/flutter/bin:/usr/local/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:${PATH}"

# Run flutter doctor
RUN flutter doctor -v
# Enable flutter web
RUN flutter config --enable-web

# Copy files to container and build
RUN mkdir /app/
COPY . /app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN flutter build web

# Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Expected in the docker file:
[image]

Got in the docker file:

[image]

flutter version local

[image]

Edit:

Thanks @Ankush Chavan
I fixed my problem
My updated docker file
Updated Dockerfile:

```
    #Stage 1 - Install dependencies and build the app
    FROM dart:3.1.0 as build-env

    ARG 2.4.1

    RUN apt-get update --quiet --yes
    RUN apt-get install --quiet --yes \
        unzip \
        apt-utils

    RUN dart pub global activate fvm 2.4.1
    RUN fvm install 3.13.1
    RUN fvm global 3.13.1
    ENV PATH="/root/fvm/default/bin:${PATH}"
    # Run flutter doctor
    RUN flutter doctor -v
    # Enable flutter web
    RUN flutter config --enable-web

    # Copy files to container and build
    RUN mkdir /app/
    COPY . /app/
    WORKDIR /app/
    RUN flutter pub get
    RUN flutter build web

    # Stage 2 - Create the run-time image
    FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
    COPY --from=build-env /app/build/web /usr/share/nginx/html
    COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: Can you please include more details like: 1. Is the Flutter SDK version on your local and docker container is same? 2. Where exactly are you setting the color?

Comment: How do I find SDK version inside docker container? The colors are the default flutter app colors no change

Comment: While installing flutter in docker, make sure your are installing specific version that required. In the Dockerfile you have shared, you are installing the flutter by cloning the flutter git repo. That's not a good approach since every new commit will be pulled in when you run the dockerfile and it might break your code. It's recommended to install dependencies with specific version that you required.